# How to pass in a SQL parameter when its too long

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I have a very big 'Where' statement that's longer then the maximum allowed.

Currently I build the full sql in the vb.net code and I execute it.

The problem is that this way is known to be slow because its not a compiled query.

Is there any other way to do it?

EDIT:

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To List.Count - 1
        If Filter = String.Empty Then
            Filter = " Where OrderID = "
        Else
            Filter += " OR OrderID ="
        End If
        Filter = Filter + "(" & List(i) + ")"
    Next

    Sql = "Select * from OrderPickSheet " & Filter & " And Status > -1 Order by SortOrder"
    cmd.CommandText = Sql
    cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: So is the problem that its slow, or that it doesn't work?

Comment: A SP doesn't work because the paramater. is too long. hard coding the full query is slow..

Comment: @Ezi: That doesn't make sense. What parameter is too long if you make the query a Stored Procedure? And when you say "hard coding the full query is slow", where are you hard coding it? Why don't you post the query, including the current .NET code around it?

Comment: I want to print out a report for all selected rows in the list. so I take all the ID's and build a where statement. I'll add the code sample.

Comment: Who says it's too long - what's the error you get, and where? One way to make your query a bit smaller might be to replace the 'orderID = x OR orderID = y....' sequence with 'orderID IN (x, y, ...)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of constructing the SQL statement on the client, you can call a stored procedure and pass the values in a `DataTable`.  In your stored procedure, join to the values that are passed in, which means you won't need to build a long dynamic sql statement, and mitigates the risk of sql injection attack.

For example, if you create this type and procedure in your database (I'm guessing here as to the data types):

```
create type dbo.OrderIdInfo as table
(
    OrderId nvarchar(20)
)

create procedure dbo.SelectOrders
(
    @orderIds dbo.OrderIdInfo readonly
)
as

    select o.* 
    from OrderPickSheet o
        inner join @orderIds i on o.OrderId = i.OrderId
    where o.Status > -1
    order by o.SortOrder
```

You can call the procedure as shown below.  The code does run (tested in LINQPad), but VB is not my primary language, so forgive any clumsiness:

```
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim results As New DataTable

table.Columns.Add("OrderId", GetType(String))

table.Rows.Add("1")
table.Rows.Add("2")
table.Rows.Add("4")

Dim parameter As New SqlParameter("@orderIds", SqlDbType.Structured)

parameter.Value = table

Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=Test;integrated security=true")
    Using command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

        command.CommandText = "dbo.SelectOrders"
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter)

        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        results.Load(reader)

    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the SQL dynamically in a stored procedure instead of in .NET.

The query still won't be compiled, but you can pass all your variables in via comma delimited string or XML

Comment: I can't send it in because its too long

Comment: You don't have to use a long WHERE Statement. If you move the SQL creation to a stored procedure. You can use the IN statement after putting all the conditions in a table variable. And with a good index, you can improve the performance of the query even more.

Comment: I have all the id's in a list, how would I send it in to sql?

Comment: @Ezi - Have a look here on a couple of way to do it if you don't want to use TVP's as suggested by adrift . http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Answer (score 1):

You can save a fair amount of length in the SQL command (and protect yourself from SQL injection attacks, to boot) by building a set of parameters dynamically:

```
    Dim paramList As New StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 0 To List.Count - 1
        Dim paramName As String = String.Format("@p{0}", i)
        If paramList.Length > 0 Then
            paramList.Append(",")
        End If
        paramList.Append(String.Format(paramName))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, List(i))
    Next
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from OrderPickSheet Where OrderID in (" & paramList.ToString() & ") And Status > -1 Order by SortOrder"
    cmd.ExecuteReader()
```